# What is a typical keypress duration

Tags: c, embedded, firmware, hci

I'm doing some work on key press handing in a firmware project.  I've been googling to try to find what the typical duration of a key press is, particularly the minimum for a fast typist.  Surprisingly I can't find any figures for this anywhere.

Comment: You could get an estimate by just taking a reasonable typing speed (e.g. 60 wpm), average no of letters per word (say 5 + 1 space = 6), which gives key strokes per second (6), which then gives of the order of 100 ms for the key down duration. Note that debounce time is typically 10 - 20 ms, so that sets a limit on how fast even a superhuman typist could physically type.

Comment: IIRC qemu uses a default duration of 100ms, so I think somewhere around there would be a good value.

Comment: Thanks for both of those.  I've done some back of the envelope figures too, which are the same.  Also I can do some testing.  I just wondered if anyone had authoritative/research figures

Comment: If someone may end up pressing a single button over and over (to increment or decrement something), they might be faster than a fast typist typically is.  Really you need to figure the gap in timing which would differentiate legitimate inter-press times from contact bounces.  If you goal is handling things on time, consider recording the keypress as distinct from processing it.

Comment: I assume that you cannot just use a single-pole, double-throw switch/button with a debouncing circuit, right? I believe that's what they use in life-critical applications, rather than rely on arbitrary timeouts that may or may not work. Costly, but effective...

Comment: thkala you're talking about solutions, this is helpful but it isn't really what I was getting at in the question.  I'm keen to find out how long the human finger typically taps a button for.  I.e. how 'quick' is a 'quick' keypress? and how much does it vary?

Comment: If I wanted to take data, I'd consider using the button to gate a 5 or 10 KHz audio oscillator feeding into a sound card (to get around the DC blocking cap) and record a file I could examine in audio software - basically, improvise a cheap digital scope with an unlimited sampling duration.

Comment: If you look up KLM-GOMS you should be able to find the average keypress duration for each typical typing skill, I know this isn't very specific but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some recent studies on keypress timings that have published there timings. Here are two:

[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~keystroke/](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekeystroke/) (Data gathered by Kevin Killourhy and Roy Maxion as accompaniment to "Comparing Anomaly-Detection Algorithms for Keystroke Dynamics").

[Pressure-Sensitive Keystroke Dynamics](http://web.archive.org/web/20100815232416/http://jdadesign.net/2010/04/pressure-sensitive-keystroke-dynamics-dataset/) (Gathered by Jeffrey D. Allen as part of his thesis).

In summary, these studies give values roughly between 50mS and 300mS.

Comment: Thanks for those.  In summary they give 50mS-300mS ish

Comment: @Will Thank you for pointing out the timings, the second link already died and it's nice to have the info on stackexchange itself rather than it being a website pointing to dead pages that once were interesting.